# Dynamic name for ggvisoutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Suppose I have the following code in server:

```
df%>%
  ggvis(~ratio, ~height, fill = ~ps, key := ~id) %>% 
  layer_bars() %>%
  bind_shiny('rds', 'ui_rds')
```

And the following in ui:

```
fluidRow( box(title = "RD",width = 6, ggvisOutput('rds')))
```

The question is *if the name of the output is variable and change in time, 
How can I set this in ui?*

In the other words, if the code of server would be like the following:

```
x <<- "some value which will be changed reactively"
df%>%
  ggvis(~ratio, ~height, fill = ~ps, key := ~id) %>% 
  layer_bars() %>%
  bind_shiny(x, paste('ui_',x))
```

What is supposed to be the code of ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would want to do this, but `renderUI` is always a possibility to deal with dynamic `ID`s.

In my example below, the `plot_id` agument in `ggvis::bind_shiny` will be created by a `textInput`. `renderUI/uiOutput` is used to "channel" the plot to a single id `"plot_wrapped"`

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    textInput("plot_id", value = "some_id",
              "choose plot id (avoid spaces and special characters)"),
    uiOutput("plot_wrapped")
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
    observe({
      mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>% layer_points() %>%
        bind_shiny(input$plot_id)
    })

    output$plot_wrapped <- renderUI({
      ggvisOutput(input$plot_id)
    })
  }
)
```

As mentioned above tough, I suggest not to use dynamic IDs in `shiny` unless it is really necessary.